# explorer right click context menu with python?

Tags: python

I'm wondering how to go about adding a menu item to explorers right click context menu. For instance, when I right click on a file I get things like winrars "Add to archive" I want something like that and I'm wondering how to do it with python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To Add more items to explorer right click menu, you just need to add some registry keys.

For example, take a look at this site, there is some examples and some tools.

http://windowsxp.mvps.org/context_folders.htm

Comment: The utilities linked on that page are awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Adding Entries to the Standard Context Menu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753589%28VS.85%29.aspx)

[_winreg - Windows registry access](http://docs.python.org/library/_winreg.html)

Comment: The question was for Windows Explorer, not IE, though the _winreg link is useful.