# Adding a sub-menu in Windows context-menu

Tags: python, registry, windows-explorer

I want to add a sub-menu to the right-click menu of Windows. Whenever a user right-clicks on a file or a folder, my application name with the sub-menu must appear there.

How to handle this?

Comment: You may also wish to refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114853/explorer-right-click-context-menu-with-python

Answer (score 2):

You want to edit the Windows Explorer context menu. You can do this in a couple of different ways:

1. There is a utility at http://www.ghacks.net/2010/08/15/add-custom-items-to-windows-explorer-context-menu/ which provides a bit of hand-holding. It looks like it will also let you add sub-menus directly.
2. Manually add the appropriate entries in the registry; see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321379/en-us  May be useful for testing, but generally nasty.
3. Create a .reg file to add the entries automatically. A bit less error-prone, but still hazardous.