# Building a Windows Explorer Extension

Tags: c#, .net, python, windows, contextmenu

I'm looking to build an application that will rely on adding menu extensions to the menu that appears when one right clicks a file or folder. I've heard that you can build it in Python, here are the resources that I am currently looking at:

http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html

http://docs.python.org/extending/windows.html#building-on-windows

However I'm not quite sure if I'm even looking in the right direction for this kind of stuff. What should I be searching for, and is it possible to build this kind of thing in Python or will I have to learn C#/.NET?

Thanks!

Edit: Looks like these things are called context menus and involves adding entries to the registry in order to associate applications with certain file types. In that case, should I have my application listening in the background for actions from the entry? Also if you know how to do the same thing in OS X or have some nifty cross-platform thing for this, that would be really nifty!

Comment: If you're just trying to add menu items then see this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114853/explorer-right-click-context-menu-with-python - If you want to do something even more fancy, then you have to use C/C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code at [Sample code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10104/Add-a-context-menu-to-the-Windows-Explorer) .

Another way is to manipulate the Registry by using the Windows Explorer tool, like the *Open with* option. Use it to associate a file extension with opening an executable, basically. However, this technique does not add a menu item into Windows Explorer. But it's easier.